# Which one is grammatically correct: "peoples who" or "peoples which"?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns, which-who

I am very confused if I should use the pronoun "who" or "which" when referring to nations. Here is the quote:

> This was partly due to diseases, but it was also due to the African peoples, who/which were able to undermine the British at every turn.

As the word "peoples" is in the plural, I think it refers to separate African nations not to the people Africa.

So which one is grammatically correct:  "which" or "who"?

Comment: Using notional agreement, 'peoples who', like 'nations who', is acceptable (and sounds far more natural). 'Nations who' may be considered shorthand for 'nations whose people'. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peoples+who%2Cpeoples+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeoples%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeoples%20which%3B%2Cc0) seem to indicate that neither 'peoples who' nor 'peoples which' is considered unacceptable, but that 'peoples who' is preferred. The graphs are reversed for 'nations who / nations which'.

Comment: [bristol.gov.uk_ List of schools who deal with their own in-year admissions](https://www.bristol.gov.uk/documents/20182/33099/List+of+schools+who+deal+with+their+own+in-year+admissions/12fc7f47-b436-4757-b1e5-2a590e14f231) shows one corresponding example of notional agreement. Though I'd expect 'which' here {[childrensuniversity.co.uk](http://www.childrensuniversity.co.uk/home/work-with-us/local-cus/york-childrens-university/information-for-schools/)}: << For 2016/17 we will be working with the following primary schools who are all members of York Children's University. >>.

Comment: Are you saying that the African peoples as a whole were able to undermine the British (who), or referring to specific African peoples that were able to do so (which).  In the latter case you'd drop the comma and change the to those: "but it was also due to those African peoples which were able to undermine the British at every turn."

Comment: @developerwj in the context, it was specified that the British lost because every time they had to ask different African countries for help.

Comment: It does refer to separate nations, not to the people of Africa in general. *People* broadly means *races/nations/cultures* so please don’t be confused by the usual *people(s) who*. Generally, *races/nations/cultures which*, not *who*.

Could anything before *… due to the African peoples* matter, please?

What could *… the African peoples, who/which were able to undermine the British at every turn* mean but two things?

The passage did not refer to the continent, over which the British and other Europeans walked practically unopposed?

The author had a strange idea of history?

Comment: What is this *it was specified that the British lost because every time they had to ask different African countries for help*, please?

How many African countries did the British take over and in how many of those did they need help from any other country?